# Working with flask-rq2 extension in heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, redis

I followed this tutorial to run tasks with Rides Queue: 
https://flask-rq2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

First

```
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')
app.config['RQ_REDIS_URL'] = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
```

Then

```
rq = RQ(app)
default_worker.work(burst=True)
```

And After execute this line

```
job = task.queue(arg1)
```

i have faced this error:
[image]

i tried to set env vairiable FLASK_APP="app.py" i got this error again but with message

> AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'task' 18:43:49 Moving
>   job to 'failed' queue

i think there is misconfigured options related to worker but where is this in official docs?

Answer (score 0):

Changed FLASK_APP="app.py" to FLASK_APP="app:app" and worked fine but also you need to change this line default_worker.work(burst=True) to inside the method and i did not know way it's not working if i put it in main suite